# Most efficient way to partition locally ordered Parquet data for reading by Polars in global order?

Tags: python, parquet, python-polars

I have multiple series of data (e.g. A, B, C, D), where the events in each series are ordered by time. The sum of all data series by size is in the order of many 10s of GBs.

Some of the series are from external sources not under my control and some of the series are computed via reference to other series, for example perhaps A and B come from an external source and perhaps the others are calculated: `C=f(A, B)` and `D=g(A, B, C)`. Periodically it is necessary to recalculate some or all of the derived series, perhaps because the functions `f()` and `g()` are modified.

I have a separate process `h(A, B, C, D)` that needs to process each event in strict global time order, i.e. irrespective of which source the event is in. The logic inside `h()` is changed frequently causing it need to be re-run and it is imperative that `h()` runs as quickly as possible. The function `h()` is written in Python.

My current process involves a custom generator which will yield the next value in time order, where each of the files for the separate data sources is just opened and read from inside the generator. The data is currently just stored as JSON objects in each of the files.

To facilitate the need for recalculation of the data series, I am considering using Parquet to store the data, where I partition by time so I can easily find a subset of events within a specified time window and perhaps also by source (A, B, C, D) so that I don't need to rewrite the entire dataset if only a subset is modified.

I'd like to speed up the calculation by using [Polars](https://pola.rs) so that there's no need to deserialise the objects from JSON as they are read and to facilitate proper use of all the available cores.

What's the most efficient way to partition the data in Parquet such that it's possible to iterate through the data as quickly as possible using Polars and what does the approach using Polars look like?

e.g. is it to create multiple lazy data frames by reading from Parquet, then to call [`LazyFrame.merge_sorted()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.merge_sorted.html), then to call [`LazyFrame.with_columns()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.with_columns.html#)?